# bash: (HOSTNAME) : command not found [setting up a Hadoop Cluster using 1 master node and 2 slave nodes]

Tags: bash, hadoop

I need some help.

I am trying to set up a Hadoop cluster with 1 master and 2 slave nodes.

Everything was fine until I tried to go from master node to slave node using ssh.

my master node's name is:

```
hadoop@master
```

my slave nodes's names are:

```
hadoop@slave1 
hadoop@slave2
```

The problem arises when I typed `ssh slave1` in hadoop@master command prompt, it printed:

[image: Image capture from VMWare Workstation Pro]

When I went in as `su` and tried `ssh slave1`, it did not display the error message as above.

How do I solve this issue ?

Comment: most probably your ssh was not setup correctly. Try to remove the directory .ssh and again creating the ssh-keygen. This is an unusual error

Comment: You probably want to put the text from that error in the body of the question do it is searchable.

Comment: What Hadoop version? What Java version? My suggestion would be to actually install Apache Ambari, which automates Hadoop installation

Comment: hi all thanks, ive installed Hadoop-2.6.5 on CentOS 7, Java is 1.8.0.jdk